# getJSON not working with input button

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

if i have `a href` getJSON is working fine as expected (getting alert message box) but where as if i use `input button`  then it does not work (no alert message), below is my example using both `a href` and `input button`, i open the firebug and i dont see that any data in response.

**working**

```
<a href="'http://host/Myservice.svc/GetCustomerBy?GetCustomerBy?GetCustomerBy=?">GetCustomerBy</a>


 $(function () {
            $('a').click(function () {
                $.getJSON(this.href, { id: '2' }, function (customer) {
                    alert(customer.Name);
                    alert(customer.Address);
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

**not working**

```
    <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />

  $("#driver").click(function (event) {

        $.getJSON('http://host/Myservice.svc/GetCustomerBy?GetCustomerBy=?', { id: '2' }, function (customer) {

            alert(customer.Address);
            alert(customer.Name);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#driver').click(function() {
        $.getJSON('http://host/Myservice.svc/GetCustomerBy?GetCustomerBy=?', { id: '2' }, function (customer) {
            alert(customer.Address);
            alert(customer.Name);
        });
    });
});
```

Notice that the call is wrapped in a $(document).ready and that you don't need to `return false`. Also no need to use the `event` argument to the anonymous callback.

Also comparing your href address is not the same as the one you are using in the button. In the href you have:

```
http://host/Myservice.svc/GetCustomerBy?GetCustomerBy?GetCustomerBy=?
```

whereas in the button you have:

```
http://host/Myservice.svc/GetCustomerBy?GetCustomerBy=?
```

which is not the same. So make sure you use the correct address whatever this address is. [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) would have helped you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your URLs don't look right -- too many ? and `GetCustomerBy` seems to be repeated.  Shouldn't it be:

```
<input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />

$("#driver").click(function (event) {

    $.getJSON('http://host/Myservice.svc/GetCustomerBy', { id: '2' }, function (customer) {

        alert(customer.Address);
        alert(customer.Name);
    });
});
```

That would result in a URL that looks like `http://host/Myservice.svc/GetCustomerBy?id=2`